# C# date time to listbox

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-7, datetime

I have a server with a .txt file. The program is saving the page to a textfile and then it is being processed per line using count. I then need to add it to datetime and then add it to a list.

So far it is pretty good except that last part datetime and the list. I always get format exception. I have tried a few variations of try parse and parse without luck.

The times are in a list like so:

```
 06:06 AM
 06:07
 12:12 
 12:50
```

One per line

Message box shows each result at a time with no error and correct infomation.

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{

  //  MessageBox.Show(line);
      List<DateTime> Busarrivetime = new List<DateTime>();
  //  DateTime tryme = DateTime.Parse(line, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  //  MessageBox.Show(tryme.ToString());
      DateTime date;
      Busarrivetime.Add(date = DateTime.ParseExact(line,"hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // ERRORS ON THIS LINE

      count++;
}

file.Close();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Exact error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

[Here is the list I am working with](http://superdatabasehost.zapto.org/times.txt).

Comment: `ParseExact` can't parse `line` as its not in appropriate format, use `TryPraseExact`

Comment: hh:mm tt is not covering the whole datetime string isn't it?
try giving in the whole format of the line that you are reading

Comment: What is the value of line when in this iteration? My assumption would be that it is `""` because there is a blank line at the end of your text file. Try checking for `String.IsNullOrEmpty` (or just empty) before trying to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your time formats are not consistently same. For example `06:06 AM` has am/pm designator where as `12:12` doesn't.

So consider using multiple possible formats.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(item, new[] { "hh:mm tt", "HH:mm" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This should work

Comment: It seems to work okay in the message output as if there is no AM at the start all of them wont have a time indicator. and when it hit 12 its automatically changes to PM. Will try your code now. Still gives same error

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple solution

I tested with this `DateTime.ParseExact("06:06 AM ", "hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

and got an exception same as yours.

but tested with this

```
DateTime.ParseExact("06:06 AM", "hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Did not get. File is picking up trailing or leading whitespace.

Use .Trim() function :) to remove them and then test

```
DateTime.ParseExact(("06:06 AM ").Trim(), "hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it just be that there is an extra blank line at the end of the file?

```
// add this just inside your while loop
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    continue;
```

Also, you need to declare your list *before* the while loop, or you will just be getting a new list for each row instead of adding to one big list.